# Post array coming with only 500 records as output on server

Tags: php, arrays, .htaccess, ini

I have more than 3000 records and i want to pass it in post array but it will giving me only 500 array as output on server. My project is on php base.

I have tried to change below but didnt succeed.

**1) Using `.htaccess` file.**

```
php_value max_input_vars 10000
```

AND

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value max_input_vars 5000
</IfModule>
```

But in both i got

> 500 internal server error.

**2) Using `ini_set()` in my index.php file.**

```
ini_set('max_input_vars',10000);
```

This will also not worked as php.net suggest that

> 'max_input_vars' not changable because of PHP_INI_PERDIR.

**3) Using `php.ini` file.**

```
max_input_vars = 10000
```

I can do this on my local and its work but on server/cpanel i want able to find this file.

Suggest me what should i want to do to exceed array size also suggest if any other way to achieve it. Also if anyone tell me how to change it using SSL command.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you didn't have any php.ini file, you can create it in your root directory and name it as php.ini

Comment: I have tried that but didnt worked.

Comment: Can you show the code where this issue is happens?

Comment: Just i have written max_input_vars = 10000 in php.ini file and put it on root directory but didnt affected.

Comment: What does your error log say ?

Comment: Convert the data into JSON/XML on the client and pass it as a single variable? If you're using an xmlhttprequest object, you can simply pass this and pick it up on the server by file_get_contents ("php://input") and bypass all php variable restrictions.

Comment: using htaccess page not loaded and gives me 500 internal server error. using ini_set no error comes but didnt affected and didnt worked. @starkeen

Comment: Does your site work if you remove the php_value directive?

Comment: yes, if i will comment php_value max_input_vars 10000 code then site works fine without 500 server error. Its may be something appache limit issue.